# How to export powerpoint slides as image using OpenOffice

Tags: vbscript, powerpoint, openoffice.org, openoffice-impress

In C# I am able to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Powerpoint to export .ppt slides as images but it MS Office should installed on the computer.

It appears that there is an automation API for [OpenOffice](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/ProUNO/Bridge/Automation_Bridge), [forums](http://forums.fivetechsupport.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=22784) but I didn’t find any script on PowerPoint to images using VB Script?

Answer (score 0):

with OpenOffice, the best way to automate the export I found some time ago, was to automate the "save as HTML" and use the images from this export.